# Every Point on a Surface is a Boundary point or a Interior Point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces

I would like to prove that any point on a (regular) surface of dimension $k$ is either a boundary point of the surface or an interior point. I have the definitions as follows:

A regular surface with boundary of dimension $k$ is a set $S$ where for each point p in $S$ we have an open neighborhood $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ containing $p$ and an open set $U$ with injective $C^1$ mapping $\phi:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ ($U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$) such that one of the following is true:

- If $p$ is an *interior point* we have that $\phi(U) = S \cap V$
- If $p$ is a *boundary point*, we have that $\phi (U\cap \{u_k \geq 0\}) = S \cap V$ and that $p \in \phi(U \cap \{u_k = 0\})$

In the second line, the first part says that the image of $\phi$ under the half plane is equal to the intersection of some open ball with the manifold, and the second part says that our point lies on the very bottom of the half plane.

I was hoping that someone could help me prove that there are no points that are both boundary and interior points at once.

Comment: My professor gave them to us in class. Please let me know if anything should be clarified.

Comment: Is that the same for manifolds/surfaces? I have seen that as a topological definition but I have seen this half plane definition in other books as well.

Comment: You need to use the inverse function theorem to show that a $C^1$ diffeomorphism cannot map a neighborhood of the origin in $\Bbb R^k$ to a neighborhood of the origin in the half-plane.

Comment: Hi Ted, two questions for you. First, I'm not entirely sure how to prove that statement using the (local) inverse function theorem. Second, I'm still slightly confused as to what proving this statement would give me. Could you elaborate? Thanks